# Unique zero-based id for values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in a DataFrame with an identifier column.

```
data = DataFrame({'id' : [50,50,30,10,50,50,30]})
```

For each unique id, I want to come up with a new unique identifier. I'd like the ids to be sequential integers starting at 0. Here's what I have so far:

```
unique = data[['id']].drop_duplicates()   
unique['group'] = np.arange(len(unique))
unique.set_index('id')
data = data.merge(unique, 'inner', on = 'id')
```

This works but seems a little dirty. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is what [`pandas.factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) does:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [50,50,30,10,50,50,30]})
print pd.factorize(data.id)[0]
```

The output:

```
[0 0 1 2 0 0 1]
```

[`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) can also do this:

```
import numpy as np
print np.unique([50,50,30,10,50,50,30], return_inverse=True)[1]
```

the output:

```
array([2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1])
```

the index outputed by `numpy.unique` is sorted by value, so the smallest value 10 is assigend to index 0. If you want this result by using `factorize`, set `sort` argument to `True`:

```
pandas.factorize(data.id, sort=True)[0]
```

Comment: Is there a straightforward way to give the original data frame those new ids?

Comment: Yes. To reproduce your example, John, just do ``data['group'] = pd.factorize(data.id)[0]``. Alternatively, you could _replace_ the old ids by assigning to ``data[id] = ...`` instead. (Did I understand your question?)